# Перепощивать или перепащивать?

Tags: орфография, неологизмы

Когда участники делают перепосты, они *переп**о**щивают* или *переп**а**щивают*?

Answer (score 1):

1) В текстах встречаются **оба варианта**: Не люблю **перепащивать**, но тут не удержался. Несмотря на принципиальную нелюбовь **перепощивать** написанное другими, делаю это сейчас.

2) Можно предположить, что здесь должно быть **обычное чередование О/А** для глаголов с суффиксом **ЫВА/ИВА**: перепостить – **перепащивать** (сравнить: пересмотреть – пересматривать) , но основа в этом случае искажается до неузнаваемости.

3)   Можно предположить, что  **лучше сохранить корневую гласную**: перепостить – **перепощивать.**

4) В то же время оба варианта **неблагозвучны и не нравятся пользователям:**  "Когда кто-то хочет разместить чужой пост у себя, используют ужасные слова "перепощивать" или "перепащивать". Режет и слух, и зрение, и в горле першит".

5) **Как быть?** Может быть, **отказаться от чередования** СТ/Щ:  перепостить - перепостивать? Или лучше так: пусть глагол будет **двувидовым**: я не люблю (что делать?) перепОстить чужое. Также виды могут различаться **ударением**: перепОстить  и перепостИть, сравнить: разрЕзать и разрезАть. **В общем, язык находится в поиске подходящей формы для этого нужного слова.**

Answer (score 0):

А сделаем-ка напрашивающуюся аналогию...

Когда слово активно употребляется, но ещё не фиксируется словарями, вспоминаем (подбираем) прецедент.

Пост - рост, подходит?

Часто встречающийся вопрос: нарощенные или наращенные волосы-ресницы-ногти?

На запрос "нарощенный" словари отвечают так:

> Искомое слово отсутствует
>
> Похожие слова:
>
> **навощённый**; кр. ф. -ён, -ена
>
> **налощённый**; кр. ф. -ён, -ена
>
> **намощённый**; кр. ф. -ён, -ена (от намостить)
>
> **наращённый**; кр. ф. -ён, -ена

Тогда зашвыриваю им "пророщенный", ответ:

> пророщенный; кр. ф. -ен, -ена (в проф. речи) и проращённый; кр. ф.
>   -ён, -ена

То есть, как мы видим, всё дело в ударении.

И тогда вопрос к автору вопроса: Вы пОстите или постИте?

В первом случае - от пОстить - будут формы запощенный и перепощенный,

во втором - от постИть - запащённый и перепащённый.

Напоминаю правило:

> В корне -рос- / -раст- (-ращ-) на месте безударного гласного   перед 
>   **с** пишется буква   **о**,   перед **ст, щ**   –   буква   **а**:
>
> росли   –   растение   –   приращивание.
>
> Исключения:  отрасль,   росток,   на вырост,   ростовщик (Ростов,
>   Ростислав)    и   слова,   от   них   образованные.

То же с корнем чихвост: чихвОстить - начихвОщивать - расчихвОщивать,

то есть всегда ударное *о* не предполагает наличия вариантов.

Comment: *во втором - от постИть - запащённый и перепащённый,* - русскоязычный человек столько не выпьет. ))) **"Перепощёный" - как "раскрепощёный"**, тут однозначно. Методологически же Вы совершенно безосновательно переносите то, что справедливо для одного-единственного исконно русского чередования (т. е. идёт от глубокой древности), на современное заимствование Оно бы ничего, но сначала извольте показать, что эта парадигма (o<ст) вообще продуктивна в современном языке. с "А<>0"  еще ожно согласиться, но не с этим.  Тоже и с "хвостом".

Comment: Будьте проще:)  неопр. форма: перепОстить. Он перепОстил.  Про прилагательное и прочие формы вопроса не было.

Comment: Это весьма спорно. Одни пОстят, другие постЯт! )))

Comment: ПостИть следует только по постным дням. :)

Comment: Постить кого/что? )))

Answer (score 0):

Рискну дать второй ответ, отдельно, поскольку он не совсем в духе первого.

Пока пытался объясниться с Galina Avanesova, пришло в голову следующее. 
Такие длинные формы, что с А - что с О, обычно нежизнеспособны.

Поэтому очень даже вероятно, что язык пойдет по другой модели вторичной имперфективации, с суффиксальным чередованием (а не вставлением суффикса типа ова/ыва).

Перепостить - перепощать.

https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=726zV-_iH4bP6ASx7KGgCA

Эврика! **Они перепощают**!

Answer (score 0):

"Перепащивать" вообще отдает чем-то совсем не соответствующим теме...

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я знаю, слово не фиксируется пока ни одним словарём, так что можно предположить любой вариант.

Вообще этот шаблон, сохранившийся едва ли не с ПИЕ-времен (с заменой корневой гласной для образования видовременной формы глагола), сейчас становится снова весьма продуктивным, так что можно предположить, что вариант **"перепащивать"** в конечном счете победит.

Впрочем, меня куда более интересует, насколько оправдана в данном случае замена "ст" на "щ". Мне так варианты "перепосчивать" или даже "перепостчивать" кажутся как минимум не менее естественными.

Comment: А что такое ПИЕ-времена? Или там опечатка?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  ПИЕ=Пра-Индо-Европейский. Достаточно распространенное сокращение. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA

Comment: Да, с 'сч' вопрос интересный. Я выбрал более распространённое в наблюдаемом. Гугл мне даёт ощ - 9000; ащ - 2800 ; осч - 2500;  асч - 300.

Comment: Тот же вопрос с *чихвостить*. Гугл мне на *чихвощивать* и *чихващивать* даёт ноль.

Comment: @horsh Правильно, что ноль. Нет такой формы, она не нужна. Хивостить - глагол несовершенного вида, зачем его делать дважды несовершенным.  Посмотрите на "расчиващивать". Впрочем, Гугл вообще источник совершенно не авторитетный, а вопрос этот выходит за раки темы, ваи же обозначенной.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. А гугл мне тогда не объяснил, что это, однако.

Comment: Исправления: @horsh Правильно, что ноль. Нет такой формы, она не нужна. Чивостить - глагол несовершенного вида, зачем его делать дважды несовершенным. Посмотрите на "расчихващивать". Впрочем, Гугл вообще источник совершенно не авторитетный, а вопрос этот выходит за раки темы, вами же обозначенной.